# C# and Java method difference

Tags: c#, java

In Java you can do the following:

```
obj.addMethod(new objMethod(){
    @override
    public void onMethod(){
        //handle this
    }
});
```

How would you do this in C#?

Comment: That's called a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx).

Comment: Using a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173171.aspx) probably.

Comment: You're missing Java's lambda expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# there are first class functions. Which means they are regular variables. 
You can parse a function with lambda expression

```
doMethod( (param1, param2)=>{
    //function body 
})
```

In Your case

```
obj.addMethod(() => {
     //body 
  })
```

And in implementation

```
public void addMethod (Action f) 
{
   f() //to invoke 
}
```

@OffTopic
It's probably the best thing C# has which Java doesn't. But they say Java 8 will introduce lambda expressions

Comment: My bad. Did it add lambdas ? How do they look?